# How to parse a JSON to a model using node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm just starting with Node.js development and I did the basic setting up code to create a server and make some requests. I'm using the MVC pattern to do this and I wanna know how can I take a json body and put inside of a model. I'm already using `body-parser` to convert to json.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
```

So if the body comes something like this :

```
{
  "Name":"Elton",
  "Password" : "SomeString"
}
```

I'm able to get the content with `req.body` as a response, but not handling individually !

```
exports.post = (req, res, next) => {
res.status(201).send(req.body);
}
```

How to pass this data to a model so I could handle each one of them  ? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by **handing individually**. If everything goes alright, **req.body** is already the parsed object, you can access **Name** value by **req.body.Name**.

Comment: Oh really ? So that's it. Cuz in C# or Java I need to create a class with getters and setters and then parse the json to this class so I could access the value with the object. Well, Thanks!

Comment: That's what **bodyParser** middleware does. it parse JSON body to a real object.